# How to move contacts and other data from Symbian to Android?

Tags: contacts, sms, calendar, data-transfer

I am changing my mobile from Symbian (**Nokia 5800 XpressMusic - S60v5**) to Android (**Samsung Galaxy SII**).
I want to move the following data from my old mobile to the new one somehow.

- Contacts
- Calendar Entries
- Bookmarks
- Notes
- *SMS, if possible*

Other data like images, videos etc I can transfer using my memory card.

I have synced my contacts,notes already to Ovi Sync and calendar entries to Google calendar via Mail for Exchange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As devnul3 has said, using Google for the contacts and calendar (I was using Google as an Exchange account, so I didn't have to do anything special). Just set your Android up with the same Google account.

Moving SMSs can be done with [*SMS Migrator*](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.baole.app.mainimporter), which can be found in the Android market. There's also the [SPB migration tool](http://spb.com/android-software/migration), which looks like it can do everything but notes.

Answer (score 4):

For contacts and calendar entries, move the contacts to the google cloud with [google sync](http://www.google.com/mobile/sync/), then activate the android device with the same account.

Note:if you created more than one google calendar, you will need to make sure they're all selected for sync on the phone (open the calendar app, menu > more > calendars).

Not sure about notes/SMS/bookmarks, although if you can get the bookmarks off of symbian and into chrome you can use [chrome marks](http://www.androidcentral.com/android-quick-app-chromemarks-browser-bookmark-sync) or chrome to phone to move them to android.