# SMS sort-by-date mixed up after transfer from Nokia (Symbian) to Android

Tags: sms, backup, restore

I know this question has been asked quite a few times. However, please read ahead.

I have tried a lot of apps such as VeryAndroid SMS Backup, SMS Backup & Restore, WonderShare MobileTrans. I also used an android app called SMS Tools which took the `.csv` file created by Nokia OVI Suite. *Most of them work. The SMS messages were threaded as per the contact name.* **However, they were not sorted as per date & time.** In other words, what I would expect is to get the latest SMS (sent or received) at the top, followed by the next latest.

Is there any way we can transfer the SMS messages in such a way that latest appear at the top & the hierarchy is followed? I've already tried the solutions offered by [How can I copy SMSes from Nokia N8 to Android for free?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/55938), [this answer on SMS transfer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/9465/16575), [SMSes from Nokia 6300](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/27154/16575), and [How to move contacts and other data from Symbian to Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/12836/16575) to no avail: They all restore the messages, but they are not ordered as per time. Even editing the `.csv` file accordingly did not have the desired effect.

Comment: Which of the [sms+nokia questions on our site](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=sms+nokia) have you checked already, so we can rule out their solutions? There's e.g. [How can I copy SMSes from Nokia N8 to Android for free?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/55938/16575) / [this answer on SMS transfer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/9465/16575) / [Import SMSes from Nokia 6300](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/27154/16575) / [How to move contacts and other data from Symbian to Android?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/12836/16575)

Comment: @Izzy: I tried this [How can I copy SMSes from Nokia N8 to Android for free?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/55938), [this answer on SMS transfer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/9465/16575), [SMSes from Nokia 6300](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/27154/16575), [How to move contacts and other data from Symbian to Android?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/12836/16575). They all restore the messages but they are not ordered as per time,

Comment: I also looked into 26 other results from [sms+nokia questions on our site](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=sms+nokia). Has anyone successfully restored SMS to Android from Symbian `keeping the messages ordered by time`?

Comment: Just a thought: I did not see those `.csv` files, and especially not their order. Maybe pre-sorting that file would do the trick? You could e.g. import it into Libre/Open-Office Calc (or Excel), sort it by the date/time column (if there's one, which I assume), export it back to `.csv`, and then restore the sorted file to your Android device.

Comment: @Izzy: Tried that too. Did not work.

Comment: Oh – that's bad. I've updated your question accordingly – but with that ruled out, I'm out of further ideas, sorry.

Comment: If your Android is Samsung, you can try http://samsung.com/smartswitch. The imported threads appear sorted by date latest->oldest in my phone.

Answer (score 4):

I think the sorting problem depends on your messaging app. Many stock messaging app doesn't sort messages by date but by received time.

The AOSP messaging app does sort by date (in cyanogenmod at least). [Textra](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.textra) does (4.0+), [Go SMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gosms) too, and also the new [Hangouts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.talk) app (4.0+).

Comment: The app need not sort by itself. But if the restoring is done such that the messages are shown in sorted order, it would be good. For instance, if I use only Android & back up and restore messages using MyBackup Android app, the order is maintained.

Comment: So have a look at the format that your Android backups have and see if you can mimic it for the Nokia messages.

Answer (score 3):

1. Connect your Nokia handset and start Nokia Ovi Suite on your PC
2. Create a backup .nbu file (it doesn't matter what you select for backup, as long as it includes messages)
3. Download NBU Explorer (open-source program which allows you to explore .nbu backup files and export them)
4. Run NbuExplorer.exe > File > Open > Browse to your .nbu file and open it
   Go to the Messages tab and click on "Export Messages" button located above the table on the right pane
5. in the "Save as type" field, select (*.xml) and save the file
6. I wrote a little tool which converts the .xml file to the format accepted by theSMS
7. Backup & Restore Android application. Download XML2Android.exe
8. Save the tool in the same folder where you saved the .xml extracted file
9. Open the command line console (Win7: Start > type "cmd" and press enter)
   CD to the directory where you saved the files (e.g. CD C:\my_messages)
   Execute: XML2Android  (e.g. XML2Android my_sms.xml)
10. This will generate a file called AndroidSMS.xml, copy this file to your Android phone
    On your Android, download the SMS Backup & Restore app from Google Play

Now, simply run the app on your phone and Restore your old messages from the generated XML file. You're done!

Comment: Worked a treat. Good job

Answer (score 0):

1. Download Mobiletrans, run it.
2. Connect your Nokia and Android at a time via USB
3. Click "Start Copy" to transfer contacts, text messages, photos and videos from Nokia to the Android.

It was developed by Wondershare, you can download it from [here](http://www.lovemediasoft.com/phone-transfer.shtml)

Edit: Maybe you can have a try with [Samsung Switch Mobile](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/909/moving-nokia-content-to-an-android-phone/71435#71435), created by Sumsang

Comment: What's your relationship with this software? Promoting your own products is OK on this site, as long as you admit that's what you're doing.